# Creating tar fills system cache

Tags: cache, tar

My situation is pretty simple: I backup-ed some of my documents and put them on a NAS and since I rather transfer one big file instead of million small ones, I created a tar

```
tar cf backup/2013-07-12-pictures.tar Pictures
```

My `Pictures` directory contains about 12GB of data and what happens is, that my cache fills up steadily. If I tar some more files (e.g. my projects, whatever) it doesn't take long and all of my **32GB RAM** are used:

```
sheldor:~$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            31         31          0          0          0         27
-/+ buffers/cache:          2         28
Swap:           29          0         29
```

At this point, although the mouse and the system is in general responsible, starting programs (which reads from disk) takes ages. Literally ages: I have an SSD and starting Chrome which usually takes a second needs now about 2 minutes.

Now you find all those posts on the internet about that it is bad to clear the cache and so on. Here, on *Ask Ubuntu* you [find such a post too](https://askubuntu.com/q/80133/65285) which saved my life by providing the command

```
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

If you read through the comments, you find for instance this here:

> This is not a problem, this is how the page cache works. It will keep things cached as long as possible, **but release items automatically when memory pressure from other applications increases.** Clearing it up manually is unnecessary. – Caesium Nov 22 '11 at 16:08

What? My system (Intel Core i7 3.50GHz × 8, 32GB RAM, NVidia Gtx 590) was frozen after a simple tar. I mean, how much pressure do I have to make before my cache is freed automatically?

**Question:** Is there a way to tweak settings so my cache gets cleared more often? Or is this just something I have to live with?

Comment: I think you may be interested in learning about the 'low-latency' kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that cache handling in Linux is far from optimal. In fact, in many regards Linux still feels more optimized for server/workstation use than desktop use. See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339951/why-arent-the-bfq-and-bfs-schedulers-included-in-the-official-ubuntu-kernel) for a similar problem with CPU/IO-scheduling.

With that said, there are solutions out there that can alleviate the problem. You can manually clear the cache or set up a cronjob, like [user197590](https://askubuntu.com/a/355584/813729) pointed out. Another method would be to disable cache generation for specific applications. You can do so with the [`nocache`](https://github.com/Feh/nocache) utility. At the moment it's only available in the [13.10 repos](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nocache) but I was able to install the Saucy package on 12.04 without any problems.

`nocache` is fairly straightforward to use. You prepend it to any command you want to execute without cache, e.g.:

`nocache tar cf backup/2013-07-12-pictures.tar Pictures`

It's not a causal solution but it can most definitely cure the symptoms of overzealous caching.

Comment: I would upvote your answer but it seems I'm out of rep. I'm not used to have only 11 points. Honestly, I really thought there must be a simple (configuration) solution, because I'm sure a new Ubuntu user would go nuts when he hears about `cron` or freeing the cache manually. On the other hand, new users maybe don't recognize that there is a caching problem. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I tried your solution and, although it doesn't solve the problem completely, it seems to slow down the increase in cache memory.

Comment: @halirutan. That's good to hear! You might be able to improve your results a bit by following the instructions in the  ['Limitations' section](https://github.com/Feh/nocache#limitations) of the github page. Please also note that `nocache` comes with some [diagnostic utilities](https://github.com/Feh/nocache#testing) that could help you ascertain what files are causing the cache fill.

Answer (score 2):

The use of memory prefetching deamon such as **preload** is the best possible solution I've found.
It does the same as MS Windows prefetch mechanism.

From [preload website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/preload/):

> preload is an adaptive readahead daemon. It monitors applications that
>   users run, and by analyzing this data, predicts what applications
>   users might run, and fetches those binaries and their dependencies
>   into memory for faster startup times.

Preload is for sure in 12.04 default repo, so

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

And that's it. Preload will learn what apps are you using and take care of filling the cache with right files.

I've used it on HDD and SSD PCs with a great effect.

Comment: Even with preload installed large file operations still have a significant impact on system responsiveness and interactivity. It's definitely an improvement but not a complete solution (unfortunately none of the methods currently outlined in the answers are).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually free up the memory cache with the following simple command:

```
sk@sk:~$ sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

However, if you want to force the Linux OS to clear the memory cache on a particular interval, just add the command to cron job. Here, I show you how.

Open up your terminal and enter the following command to create a file called cacheclear.sh. Say for example, I create cacheclear.sh file in my /home directory:

```
sk@sk:~$ sudo vi /home/cacheclear.sh
```

Add the following lines to cacheclear.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Save and exit the file. Now add this file to the root crontab:

```
sk@sk:~$ sudo crontab -e
```

This command opens the root crontab.

Add the following line to the end:

```
0 * * * * /home/cacheclear.sh
```

Save and exit the file. Once you’re done, the cron job will run this command every hour and will clear the system memory caches.