# why is my memory cache so big?

Tags: 20.04, ram, cache

right now I have only a browser tab running on my laptop, but when I open `system monitor`, in memory section, It shows:
3.2 GiB (23.2%) of 13.7
Cache 6.1 GiB

why is my Cache so big? is it usual?,
and I don't actually get the difference between the 3.2 GiB  in use and the 6.1 GiB cache, but if the cache is also a part of the used memory, isn't it so much that 9.5 of my 14 GiB ram is full?

p.s: the output of `free -g` is
total = 13, used = 2, free=4, available =10, and swap is fully free

p.s2: I've also saw [Why is the cache in my memory always full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80133/why-is-the-cache-in-my-memory-always-full), but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you have any issues (with performance or similar) that suggests that enough memory is not available ? Ubuntu / Linux will use unused memory for caching, and release memory from cache when it is needed for other stuff. Caching speeds up IO, so it is a good thing. Also, unused memory is wasted memory.

Comment: @SorenA sometimes when I open multiple programs or heavy ones, although I have enough free ram, system gets a little bit of lag which seems to be because of ram(if i haveguessed it right), today when I saw the big size of cache, I thought that it may be because of it?

Comment: Lag when opening programs or large files are often related to IO reading the files from disk (when thet are not in cache), more than releasing cache from ram. And as long as there are free memory cache isn't an issue. Do you have any indications that your system is swapping/paging heavily ?

Comment: I actually meant sometimes while using(not opening) multiple programs or heavy programs system becomes laggy(although I have free memory,(so I thought it may be because of unreleased cache?))     
after all, It's really "sometimes" and doesn't happen everyday

Comment: I'd guess that by "cache", it may mean disk cache. When you access files on disk, they get cached in free memory the system has for efficiency. If you load that file again and the data on disk hasn't changed, the OS can just re-load it very quickly out of memory instead of querying the, much slower, disk again. Free memory isn't doing anything useful so the system may as well use it as disk cache.